# How to preempt webservice call deployed on weblogic

Tags: java, web-services, security, weblogic11g

I am not sure if the subject clearly identifies what i am trying to do, please suggest if you need any update to make it more clear.

Here what i need to do.

We have a webservice deployed on weblogic owned by different entity. We have been consuming the webservice in our application and accessing data.
However, we have a security requirement, that is once the webservice call is invoked, before invoking webservice the container shall check if the user is authorized or not.

We do have a java utility that does this for us, so precisely, i need to invoke that utility before the webservice call is invoked. As the webservice is owned by a different entity, i was wondering if weblogic allows us some hook to add on this security layer?

Any idea/suggestion on this?